# OpenCV not detecting QR code in the image

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I have been trying to detect and decode QR codes from captured images through phone. I have been facing trouble to decode [picture a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWEgm.jpg) as the script is failing to detect there is QR code here. However, if I crop just the QR code as in [picture c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTKFP.png) the script is able to decode the code. What modification do I need to make in the script to make it work in picture a?`

```
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol

image_path = "Test_Image.png"


img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0) 
ret, bw_im = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

code = decode(bw_im, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
print (code)

for barcode in decode (bw_im, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE]):
    print (barcode.data) 
    print (barcode.rect)
    myData = barcode.data.decode ('utf-8')
    print (myData)
    break
```

Comment: In your images, is the QR code always in the centre of the image?

Comment: Not really. The positions are also different in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to experiment, both [pyzbar](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar) and [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) perform pretty well for decoding, but they have some problems with detecting difficult QRs. You could try [QReader](https://github.com/Eric-Canas/qreader) for your use case. It uses [pyzbar](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar), sweetened with some image preprocessing fallbacks, on the decoding side, so the decoding performance will be quite similar to the one you are using now. However, for the detection part, it uses a [YoloV7](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) based [QR detector](https://github.com/Eric-Canas/qrdet) that heavily increases the detection rate on difficult images.

```
from qreader import QReader
import cv2

image_path = "Test_Image.png"

# Create a QReader instance
qreader = QReader()

# Get the image (as RGB)
image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Use the detect_and_decode function to get the decoded QR data
decoded_texts = qreader.detect_and_decode(image=image)

# Print the results
for text in decoded_texts:
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be renamed to "Pyzbar not detecting QR code in the image" since you are just using OpenCV for loading the image/image processing.

Regardless, I have run into a similar issue as you, and I think the limitation is that opencv and pyzbar perform worse the smaller the QR code is relative to the entire image.

In my case, I already had some bounding boxes around the objects that had the QR code on them so I just search within the bounding box, and the smaller search area improves detection/decoding.

Depending on your efficiency requirements, you could try to do a coarser search, finding certain shapes in the image or objects that have a certain color and then use the QR search in those regions of interest. If you need to do real-time processing or keep computational overhead low then this may not be feasible.

You could also just apply some default cropping to your image, which won't be very robust if your QR code is going to be moving around, but would reduce the search area and improve the detection/decoding.